# How to send mail by attaching screenshot which is from html2canvas by using Java not with PHP

Tags: java, email

Am new to Java, I have taken a screenshot of file using html2canvas, Now I need to send mail by attaching that screenshot using Ajax with Java. am able to send mail without screenshot but I need to send with screenshot and am not getting where the screenshot file is storing.

Once I get the screenshot by using html2canvas so am not able to do this is it possible to send screenshot without using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

html2canvas doesn't save your image but its base 64 decoded stream. You can generate a base64DecoderStream and then send an email using the Java mail API. Hope this helps.

Thanks.